# Android AddRule to Button in TableLayout/TableRow?

Tags: android

I am using the following code to progmatically add buttons to an activity based on items received from a JSON response:

```
TableLayout layout_events = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_events);

JSONArray json = new JSONArray(output);

for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++)
{
    JSONObject object = json.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONObject tournament = object.getJSONObject("tournament");

    Button button = new Button(this);
    button.setSingleLine(true);
    button.setText(tournament.get("name").toString());

    TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
    row.addView(button);

    layout_events.addView(row);
}
```

This working fine. However, I would like the buttons to stretch the full width of the table. How would I get this done?

I tried something along the lines of:

```
TableRow.LayoutParams layout = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
    TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

button.setLayoutParams(layout);
```

But this doesn't work since TableRow.LayoutParams does not have a `addRule()` function.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put `android:stretchColumns="*"` property in your `TableLayout`.

or

you can add weight as 1 for button programatically.

```
TableRow.LayoutParams layout = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
    TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1f);
```

you have to set ellipsize programatically.

```
button.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
```

Comment: That sort of works... but then the buttons don't respect the "setSingleLine" option correctly. Yes, they are single line, but they dont cut off with ellipses at the max width... instead they stretch beyond the layout.

Comment: this is interesting @JasonAxelrod

Comment: Updated answer does stop it from stretching beyond the boundaries... but it doesn't add the ellipsis.

Comment: can you please add a very long text and try again? and also I notice that you have not set ellipsize  programatically may be that is causing issue.

Comment: my pleasure @JasonAxelrod